# Joining next Sequential Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I am planing an SQL Statement right now and would need someone to look over my thougts.

This is my Table:

```
id  stat    period
--- ------- --------
1   10      1/1/2008
2   25      2/1/2008
3    5      3/1/2008
4   15      4/1/2008
5   30      5/1/2008
6    9      6/1/2008
7   22      7/1/2008
8   29      8/1/2008
```

Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE tbstats
  (
     id     INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     stat   INT NOT NULL,
     period DATETIME NOT NULL
  )

go

INSERT INTO tbstats
            (stat,period)
SELECT 10,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20080101')
UNION ALL
SELECT 25,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20080102')
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20080103')
UNION ALL
SELECT 15,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20080104')
UNION ALL
SELECT 30,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20080105')
UNION ALL
SELECT 9,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20080106')
UNION ALL
SELECT 22,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20080107')
UNION ALL
SELECT 29,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20080108')

go
```

I want to **calculate** the difference between each statistic and the next, and then calculate the mean value of the 'gaps.'

Thougts:

I need to join each record with it's subsequent row. I can do that using the ever flexible joining syntax, thanks to the fact that I know the id field is an integer sequence with no gaps.

By aliasing the table I could incorporate it into the SQL query twice, then join them together in a staggered fashion by adding 1 to the id of the first aliased table. The first record in the table has an id of 1. 1 + 1 = 2 so it should join on the row with id of 2 in the second aliased table. And so on.

Now I would simply subtract one from the other.

Then I would use the ABS function to ensure that I always get positive integers as a result of the subtraction regardless of which side of the expression is the higher figure.

**Is there an easier way to achieve what I want?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average value of the gaps can be done by calculating the difference between the first value and the last value and dividing by one less than the number of elements:

```
select sum(case when seqnum = num then stat else - stat end) / (max(num) - 1);
from (select period, row_number() over (order by period) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as num
      from tbstats
     ) t
where seqnum = num or seqnum = 1;
```

Of course, you can also do the calculation using `lead()`, but this will also work in SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 2):

The [`lead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) analytic function should do the trick:

```
SELECT period, stat, stat - LEAD(stat) OVER (ORDER BY period) AS gap
FROM   tbstats
```

Comment: Im sorry that I did not mention the SQl Server Version in my Question, though this may work in newer Versions, it does not for me

Answer (score 1):

By using Join also you achieve this

```
SELECT t1.period,
       t1.stat,
       t1.stat - t2.stat gap
FROM   #tbstats t1
       LEFT JOIN #tbstats t2
              ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the difference between each statistic and the next, [LEAD() and LAG()](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/) may be the simplest option. You provide an `ORDER BY`, and LEAD(*something*) returns the next *something* and LAG(*something*) returns the previous *something* in the given order.

```
select
  x.id thisStatId,
  LAG(x.id) OVER (ORDER BY x.id) lastStatId,
  x.stat thisStatValue,
  LAG(x.stat) OVER (ORDER BY x.id) lastStatValue,
  x.stat - LAG(x.stat) OVER (ORDER BY x.id) diff
from tbStats x
```